# Protractor and Appium using WD good idea?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

We've built an app using Cordova. Automated tests are implemented using Protractor and Appium, followed [this guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/mobile-setup.md). This works OK, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. We run into some random failed tests.
Then I read this on the [WebDriver Github site](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/README.md):

> It is possible to use wd to test mobile devices using either Selenium or Appium. However in either case the full JsonWire protocol is not supported (or is buggy).

If I read this correctly, using WebDriver with Appium is buggy. 
But even Appium has examples where they are using WebDriver, see [here](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/node/android-webview.js).

I'm not sure what the alternative is, maybe [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/)? But I can't find much documentation about it. Or did I read it wrong, and should we be using wd without issues here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your specific question, Protractor, Selendroid, and WebdriverIO (amongst others) are all JavaScript implementations of (Selenium 2.0) WebDriver - which is a layer/protocol/API through which you can query and control Appium. Bindings exist in all sorts of languages: python, Java, etc.

So, **yes**, it is perfectly possible to use Protractor and Appium together.

(I wouldn't *personally*, because I still associate Protractor with AngularJS applications, plus it is by no means the only game in town for JavaScript WebDriver. However, that is not down to bugs or lack of support.)

I'd definitely want to query the quote on Mr. Christian's site - which **not** the official WebDriver Github site by any means. It's not wrong, but the [WebDriver spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) is big, and hardly anyone implements all of it. So I'd take the statement with a pinch of salt.

Having established that your basic approach is **not** at all wrong, it would be good to explore your random failed tests, and to work out where the issues lie.

Certainly as far as newbies go, a very large proportion of "random" failures are completely avoidable race conditions within their test code, but even more experienced users will have to deal with the same problem in other forms.

Comment: Hi thank you that is a very good answer! It makes much more sense now. I'll investigate looking at some other framework than Protractor, to see if that fixes my issues. My test just randomly fail, which must be indeed some timing issue.
But thanks again!